# TinyMCE 5.7 failure callback returns "[object Object]" no matter what

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

Seemingly strange problem here: I've got TinyMCE 5.7 up and running with the *images_upload_handler* function configured [per the docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/upload-images/#images_upload_handler). If the upload is a success, everything works great. However, if the upload is a failure, then the dialog box that *should* output the failure message simply outputs "[object Object]".

[Screenshot: Failure callback output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrlGM.jpg)

I find that this is the case whether I invoke the failure callback in the *images_upload_handler* function just as the docs dictate...

```
function gg_image_upload_handler (blobInfo, success, failure, progress) {
    [...]
    
    if (xhr.status < 200 || xhr.status >= 300) {
      failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
      return;
    }

    [...]
}
```

...or if I make the entire *images_upload_handler* function a failure callback with a simple string, taking all the other variables (including the PHP upload handler) out of it:

```
function gg_image_upload_handler (blobInfo, success, failure, progress) {
    failure('hello!');
    return;
}
```

Notably, if I change the second example from "failure('hello!');" to "success('hello!');" then there is no problem: When I upload a photo in that case, "hello!" appears in the dialog box where the path to the uploaded image would normally appear.

I can't find anyone else who's had an issue with the failure callback, so I fear I've done something silly, but it seems weird that everything else works and this part does not. Any thoughts? Full Javascript code follows:

```
function gg_image_upload_handler (blobInfo, success, failure, progress) {
  var xhr, formData;

  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.withCredentials = false;
  xhr.open('POST', 'handlers/tinymce_photo_handler.php');

  xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
    progress(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
  };

  xhr.onload = function() {
    var json;

    if (xhr.status === 403) {
      failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status, { remove: true });
      return;
    }

    if (xhr.status < 200 || xhr.status >= 300) {
      failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
      return;
    }
    
    json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
      failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
      return;
    }

    success(json.location);
  };

  xhr.onerror = function () {
    failure('Image upload failed due to a XHR Transport error. Code: ' + xhr.status);
  };

  formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());

  xhr.send(formData);
};

tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea#editor",
    images_upload_handler: gg_image_upload_handler,
    images_reuse_filename: true,
    skin: "oxide",
    plugins: "lists, link, image, media, image code",
    relative_urls: false,
    remove_script_host: false,
    toolbar:
    "h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 bold italic strikethrough blockquote bullist numlist backcolor | link image media | removeformat help",
    image_caption: true,
    image_advtab: true,
    image_class_list: [
        {title: 'Responsive', value: 'img-fluid'}
    ],
    content_style: 'img { max-width: 75%; height: auto; }',
    menubar: false,
    setup: (editor) => {
        // Apply the focus effect
        editor.on("init", () => {
          editor.getContainer().style.transition =
            "border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out";
        });
        editor.on("focus", () => {
          (editor.getContainer().style.boxShadow =
            "0 0 0 .2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, .25)"),
            (editor.getContainer().style.borderColor = "#80bdff");
        });
        editor.on("blur", () => {
          (editor.getContainer().style.boxShadow = ""),
            (editor.getContainer().style.borderColor = "");
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a bug introduced in TinyMCE 5.7.0 as reported here: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/6579. This will be fixed in the upcoming TinyMCE 5.7.1 patch release, however for now the best workaround is to downgrade to TinyMCE 5.6.2 sorry.

Comment: Thank you! At least that solves the mystery. My hackaround was to change the failure callbacks to success callbacks, which results in the error output being rendered where the successfully uploaded file path would normally appear. This works well enough for now, as I only need TinyMCE for the admin CMS interface (three people, not public-facing). But good to know a fix is coming.